# Merging Scripts in Linux

Tags: scripting, merge

I'm new to Linux so let me ask you this dumb question. I just download this NLP (Natural Language Processing) script (from Standford). I also have this script that can stream tweets from tweeter in real time. Now both scripts are running, I'm running it from shell. Those NLP script is in Java and the Twitter one is in Python. I would like to have the my tweets (the ones i'm streaming live) running into my NLP in real time. How do I do this?

Comment: Typically you would pipe the output of one into the input of the other.

Comment: Ok, great, yes, another word for what I want to do is piping. It still doesn't answer my question. I have a python script running and I want to pipe it my nlp bash script. How would that work using sed and grep. How do I grep a python script into a bash script. Also, how to I put the path to my script in the grep and sed command to execute those scripts.

Comment: You don't use sed or grep at all. Those are tools for manipulating text. Please go look up examples of pipelines in bash. Your shell handles redirecting the output of the first command to the input of the next. You do this like `./mytwitterfeed.sh | nlpstuff` if both are written to read from standard input and write to standard output.